# Entity Framework in n-Tier

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

Using a simple example:

- Presentation Tier : aspx and code behind.
- Business Tier: WCF with
  related logics
- Data Access Tier: WCF with entity framework

When I want to populate a grid view, there will be a need to call a method form the business logic, which in turns call the data access tier's method.

The methods and related logic are as follow.

Data Access Tier:

```
public SampleEntity[] LoadSampleEntity()
{
   //retrieve SampleEntity from database.
}
```

Business Logic Tier:

```
public SampleEntity[] GetSampleEntity()
{
   //call the proxy to access Data Access Tier
   //Call LoadSampleEntity()
}
```

Presentation Tier:

```
protected void btn_OnClick()
{
   //call the proxy to access Business Logic Tier
   //Call GetSampleEntity()
   //SampleEntity[] sampleEntity=BusinessLogic.GetSampleEntity();
   //gridview.datasouce = sampleEntity
   //gridview.databind();
}
```

Given this structure, if SampleEntity was modified, all the 3 tiers will require re-compiling.
Is there any way to reduce the need of re-compiling when new property/column is added to SampleEntity .

One way which I have worked on will be to convert SampleEntity[] to datatable type at Business Logic Tier, and pass the datatable over to Presentation Tier. However doing so removes the intellisense feature of EntityFramework in the Presentation Tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the repository pattern.  You'd first have a domain layer of objects that would be similar to your Entity objects, this domain layer would be in it's own project/dll.  You would use something like AutoMapper to map the values from the Entity object over to the Domain object, via the business layer.  Then the presentation layer would/could share the domain object layer, that way you abstract the entity data layer behind the

```
IRepository<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   T GetById(int id);
   void Save(T saveThis);
   void Delete(T deleteThis);
}
```

Your type T for each table would be the domain type and inside these methods you'd map the Entity type to your domain type.  This IRepository can be your service contract on the Data Tier access.

As for your other question any change you make to your entity object would need to be reflected in the domain object but this can be done with something like AutoMapper.  I think in most cases you don't want to share an EF or LinqToSql data type all the way out to the view or UI.

Since it's WCF you could have the Domain Layer be your serialized types.

Comment: this is useful to me. I actually do not want to expose the entity but rather do something like u did. But I'm not sure if there is a way to do this without affecting my development time. Now u r speaking of automapper. Is automapper something like object.getType()? If you don't mind, can you show me the pseudo or code in terms of the various tier? Using your method, I can see the help iRepository gives at business tier, but in terms of Presentation Tier, how should I access T?

Comment: Automapper is just a way to transfer state from one object to another for instances just like this.  You can check it out on codeplex, I use my own home-brewed reflection mapping scheme but Automapper will do it better.  Basically you'd have each table represented as it's own wcf repository service with the contract shown above (although you really can't do generic interfaces in WCF).

Comment: You would however or could however use your domain object that was represented by T in the contract/repository be shared all the way out to the presentation tier, much like you shared above with SampleEntity making it all the way to the presentation tier.  Your presentation tier would only know about the domain object that was given back to you from the IRepository service.  It would have no way to know what was inside the service that implemented this contract (where all the gritty details of datacontexts and conversions to the domain objects were done).

Comment: I did look at AutoMapper after you gave the answer. I see that I need to create a class variable 1st with the required properties. So to implement this, can I say that at the data tier, to expose the Entities, map the entity into another variable

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using the open source [N-Tier Entity Framework](https://ntieref.codeplex.com/) which uses Entity Framework on server-side and generates the entire infrastructure for building an n-tier architecture based on WCF including an EF-like API on client-side. Have a look at the framework’s user guide available for download on codeplex, it contains an entire section on architectural considerations.